# Fill array of <select> using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How could i fill array of select with options using ajax:

```
<select name = "names[1]"></select>
<select name = "names[2]"></select>
<select name = "names[3]"></select>
<select name = "names[4]"></select>
<select name = "names[5]"></select>
```

note: thats just for example, but iwant it dynamic so i dont know how many of select i do have, but all of them will contain same options.

Comment: add what json you getting from server

Comment: @SridharR {176: Object, 177: Object}
my broblem is how to get number of arrays that i have

Comment: what is Object contains

Comment: First Parse Json and check what you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

use little bit of jquery here.

```
$(function(){
var jsonArray = []; //your json array. 
var html = "";
for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
 html += "<select name="'+jsonArray.name[i]+'"></select>"
}

$("#locationId").append(html); //append your html where ever you want

})
```

Comment: no, actualy i have one json returned, and want it to fill it in many select objects